# A question about a sheaf of abelian group constructing from stalks

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Given a topological space $X$ and a sheaf of abelian groups $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$, we can construct a new sheaf of abelian groups $I(\mathcal{F})$ defined by
$$I(\mathcal{F})(U) := \prod_{x \in U} \mathcal{F}_x,$$
where $U$ is open in $X$ and $\mathcal{F}_x$ is the stalk of $\mathcal{F}$ at $x$. Here the restriction of $I(\mathcal{F})$ is the natural restriction which maps $(s_x)_{x \in U}$ to $(s_x)_{x \in V}$, and I think it should be surjective but I am not confident of myself. What do you guys think?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The map is indeed surjective. The proof of this fact is not difficult: what have you tried?

Comment: Yeh I think the restriction should be surjective since its action is just throwing away the components s_x with x lies in U\V